# join on last record

Tags: php, sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this mysql statement

```
SELECT `leads`.*,
     `lead_notes`.`lead_id`,
     `lead_notes`.`status`
  FROM `leads`
     LEFT JOIN `lead_notes` ON `leads`.`id` = `lead_notes`.`lead_id`
          WHERE `leads`.`pixel` IN (".implode(',', array_map('add_quotes', $my_pixels)).")
              AND `lead_notes`.`status`='4'
```

But I only want to join the last record in lead_notes.
Thank you

Ok, my question was not clear,I will try again
I want to get all the recoreds from leads that the last lead_notes status equals x

I have two tables

```
---table leads---           ---table lead_notes---
id  pixel   date            id  lead_id     status  date
1   uuid1   unixtime        1   5           1       unixtime
2   uuid1   unixtime        2   4           0       unixtime
3   uuid2   unixtime        3   3           2       unixtime
4   uuid1   unixtime        4   2           4       unixtime
5   uuid3   unixtime        5   1           2       unixtime
                            6   2           2       unixtime
                            7   4           4       unixtime
                            8   5           2       unixtime
                            9   1           1       unixtime
                            10  3           2       unixtime
```

I want to join lead with lead_notes on the newest one (that id matches lead_id)
and select it if the status equals x

Comment: By "last record" do you mean the one with the largest id? or is there some other field that determines order?

Comment: id, or date, both exist (data in unixtime)

Comment: I've just deleted my answer, because I have a question: What is `AND lead_notes.status='4'` for? What do you actually want to get? You are selecting the status, but it can only be 4 with this condition. So what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to know whether a lead's last status is 4? Or what else?

Comment: Okay, now that you clarified your request, I've altered my answer and undeleted it.

Comment: @phper Note that your LEFT JOIN renders as an INNER JOIN. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Strawberry: Read the question. phper wants to join first and then check for '4'. You are right however that this approach doesn't work, it merely turns the outer join into an inner join, just as you say.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner 'Read the question'? You're kidding, right?

Comment: @Strawberry: "I want to get all the recoreds from leads that the last lead_notes status equals x". Admittedly this is not much, but it shows what phper is trying.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner For what it's worth, I suspect that the answer you've provided is not what the OP is after. However, there simply isn't enough clarity in this question to say for sure.

Comment: I will edit it again

Comment: @phper If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I edited the question and added sample table

Answer (score 0):

Now that you clarified: You don't have to join at all. You want leads where the last status equals a given value (e.g. 4). So this belongs in the WHERE clause. Use ORDER BY and LIMIT to get a lead's last record.

```
select *
from leads
where
(
  select lead_notes.status
  from lead_notes 
  where lead_notes.lead_id = leads.id
  order by lead_notes.note_date desc
  limit 1
) = '4';
```

Comment: @Strawberry: I don't know. Maybe a status can either  be a digit or letter? It is a string in the original query, so I kept it such.

Answer (score -1):

```
dec @row int=0 


 SELECT `leads`.*,
 `lead_notes`.`lead_id`,
 `lead_notes`.`status`
 FROM `leads`
 LEFT JOIN `lead_notes` ON `leads`.`id` =select max(a) from (select @row=@row+1 as a from `lead_notes')
  WHERE `leads`.`pixel` IN (".implode(',', array_map('add_quotes', $my_pixels)).")
  AND `lead_notes`.`status`='4'
```

Comment: Sorry to say, this is plain wrong. You cannot use max in the ON clause. Aggreagtion is done *after* joining records.

Comment: Still very wrong, both syntactically and semantically. I don't even understand what you are *trying* to do with your variable.